# Error creating a new environment in Anaconda.Navigator

Tags: python, anaconda, symantec, zscaler

I am new to Anaconda. I installed Anaconda.Navigator **successfully**.
But when I try to create a new environment in it, I always get error like this:

CondaHTTPError: HTTP 000 CONNECTION FAILED for url https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/win-64/current_repodata.json
Elapsed: An HTTP error occurred when trying to retrieve this URL. HTTP errors are often intermittent, and a simple retry will get you on your way.If your current network has https://www.anaconda.com blocked, please file a support request with your network engineering team. https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/win-64

[image: error]

The same error I get with **Anaconda Prompt**. I called my tech support and they said no blocking on me, **all whitelisted**. Then I tried to copy-paste all those 3 links from that error text, **all can get through** via my browsers.

I have no clue. Please guide/help. Thank you.

*I am in Win10 Pro 64-bit, Symantec Endpoint Protection, Zscaler Client Connector, Anaconda Navigator 2.1.4*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Good news. I searched YouTube and found the answer for my problem.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pNqXHQUSEsc

1. Open Anaconda Powershell Prompt
2. conda create -n testenv python=3.9

That simple, many thanks to the video owner.
I never tried using the Anaconda Powershell Prompt previously.
It just solved my problem.

*Maybe I'll keep this question not deleting it, it might helps others.*